# Executing Coral Board Demonstration Model on Boot with Custom Systemd Service

Tags: systemd, google-coral

I am trying to configure my coral board to boot to the Coco object detection model using a custom systemd service. I've created the executable file, unit file and then enabled the service. The intent is for the camera feed to display to a monitor, but when I power on the board, the monitor only displays a bluish background (I assume the "home screen" of the board).

**The executable file:**

```
edgetpu_detect \
--model mobilenet_ssd...
--labels coco...
```

**The unit file:**

```
[Unit]
Description=systemd service.
After=weston.target

[Service]
PAMName=login
Type=simple
User=mendel
WorkingDirectory=/home/mendel
ExecStart=/bin/bash /usr/bin/test_service.sh
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.targer
```

**Status of service after enabling and after powering on**:

```
mendel@jumbo-tang:/etc/system$ sudo systemctl status myservice.service
myservice.service - systemd service.
    Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/system/myservice.service; enabled; vendor preset
    Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-01-06 03:32:03 UTC; 1s ago
Main PID: 4847 (bash)
     Tasks: 0 (limit: 4915)
    CGroup: /system.slice/myservice.service
            4847 /bin/bash /usr/bin/test_service.sh
Jan 06 03:32:03 jumbo-tang systemd[1]: myservice.service: Service hold-off time
Jan 06 03:32:03 jumbo-tang systemd[1]: Stopped Example systemd service..
Jan 06 03:32:03 jumbo-tang systemd[1]: Started Example systemd service..
Jan 06 03:32:03 jumbo-tang systemd[4847]: pam_unix(login:session): session opene
```

The executable is saved to `/usr/bin`, and was made executable with `sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/test_service.sh`

The unit file was saved to `/etc/systemd/system`, and was given permissions with `sudo chmod 644 /etc/systemd/system/myservice.service`

I'm curious to know if my executable cannot simply contain the code I'd normally use to launch a model, like I've done, or if my unit file is properly configured, or what else could be wrong I'm not thinking of.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Corrected, thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I've answered you via coral-support, we discussed that you're most likely just missing a couple things:

1) When starting a systemd service especially at boot, sometimes not all environment variable are loaded, in this case, you may need to add the line:

```
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
```

before ExecStart. However, I don't suspect that is is the issue, because the process does waits on weston.target, which should already waits on environment variables.

2) This one is a lot more complicated than the previous one but you misspelled

`"target" in "WantedBy=multi-user.targer" (joking, of course)`

## I'm showing the steps here again as an example for future references.

1) create a file call detects.service with the following contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=systemd auto face detection service
After=weston.target

[Service]
PAMName=login
Type=simple
User=mendel
WorkingDirectory=/home/mendel
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=/bin/bash /usr/bin/detect_service.sh
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

2) mv the file /lib/systemd/system/detects.service

```
$ sudo mv detects.service /lib/systemd/system/detects.service
```

3) create a file call detect_service.sh with the following content

```
edgetpu_detect --model fullpath/mobilenet_ssd_v2_coco_quant_postprocess_edgetpu.tflite --label fullpath/coco_labels.txt
```

4) make it executable and mv it to /usr/bin

```
$ sudo chmod u+x detect_service.sh
$ sudo mv detect_service.sh /usr/bin
```

5) enable the service with systemctl

```
$ sudo systemctl enable detects.service
```